# Regular expression to match special characters within double quotes

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

My input string is :

```
"& is here "& is here also, & has again occured""
```

Using gsub method in Ruby language, is there a way to substitute character '&' which is occuring within double quotes with character '$', if gsub method doesnt solve this problem, is there any other approach which can be used to address this problem.

Since first arguement in gsub method can be a regex, so matched regex will be substituted by the second arguement, getting a right regex for identifying might also solve this problem since it can be substituted in the gsub method for replacing '&' with '$'.

Expected output is as shown :

```
& is here "$ is here also , $ has again occured"
```

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Comment: I'd match the quoted substrings and replace the ampersands inside each match.

Comment: It can't be done in any robust way with regex.

Comment: @pguardiario: It can't be done at all with regex, given that regex is only search (it does not cover replacing). But it can be done with regex and other stuff :)

Comment: Sorry @sawa will you highlight the mistakes on my current post so I can improve on this.

Comment: @sawa I have made changes to the highlighted portions , but i dont know if its right or not , this time instead of highlighting make the corrections , so that I will get a better understanding . Thanks

Comment: @Manu In English, you shouldn't put a space before colons commas, etc., and you should end a sentence with a period or an exclamation or question mark (unless it ends with things like a block of formatted code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = %q{& is here "& is here also , & has again occured"}
str.gsub!(/".*?"/) do |substr|
  substr.gsub(/&/, '$')
end
puts str
# => & is here "$ is here also , $ has again occured"
```

EDIT: Just noticed that stribizhev proposed this way before I wrote it.

Comment: I am new to regex , can you explain the difference between /".*?"/ and /".*"/ ?

Comment: Non-greedy vs. greedy. Try them both on `'both "foo" and "bar"'`.